# Unable to install devise gem "unidentified method for install"on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When I try to perform "rails generate devise:install" I get this error message:

I've tried re-installing the devise gem multiple times. This error also comes up when I try to start up my server. I'm wondering if the cause of this is from initially trying to install the devise gem with "rails generate devise install" instead of putting a colon between devise and install.

```
    Maxs-MacBook-Air:pinteresting allecat941$ rails generate devise:install
/Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for Install (call 'Install.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
from /Users/allecat941/pinteresting/app/models/install.rb:4:in `<class:Install>'
from /Users/allecat941/pinteresting/app/models/install.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:552:in `get'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `constantize'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:297:in `get'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `new'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `add_mapping'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:221:in `block in devise_for'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `each'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `devise_for'
from /Users/allecat941/pinteresting/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:335:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:335:in `eval_block'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:313:in `draw'
from /Users/allecat941/pinteresting/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/allecat941/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/allecat941/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/allecat941/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/allecat941/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/allecat941/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /Users/allecat941/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/allecat941/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
from /Users/allecat941/pinteresting/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in `serve'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
from /Users/allecat941/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/allecat941/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/allecat941/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your accidental install created Install model and other files. Delete those, perhaps?

Comment: yes - you should revert the `rails generate devise install` with `rails destroy devise install`, because it generated a model called Install.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using the device gem and without devise install . Then use, the cmd rails g device auth in this case rails throw the error than using this method my problem is solved

```
extend Devise::Models

in my auth.rb files

class Auth < ApplicationRecord  
   extend Devise::Models  
end
```

Comment: I am using the device gem and without devise install . Then use, the cmd rails g device auth in this case rails throw the error than using this method my problem is solved.